# How to convert Dataframe to dynamic frame

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to AWS glue and I am trying to run some transformation process using pyspark. I successfully ran my ETL but I am looking for another way of converting dataframe to dynamic frame.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# load data from crawler
students = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="example_db", table_name="samp_csv")

# move data into a new variable for transformation
students_trans = students

# convert dynamicframe(students_trans) to dataframe
students_= students_trans.toDF()

# run transformation change column names/ drop columns
students_1= students_.withColumnRenamed("state","County").withColumnRenamed("capital","cap").drop("municipal",'metropolitan')
#students_1.printSchema()

#convert df back to dynamicframe
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

students_trans = students_trans.fromDF(students_1, glueContext, "students_trans")

#load into s3 bucket
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = students_trans,
              connection_type = "s3",
              connection_options = {"path": "s3://kingb/target/"},
              format = "csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from awsglue import DynamicFrame


students_trans = DynamicFrame.fromDF(students_1, self._glue_context, "df")
```